# Separation of 2D points into 2 splines for turning point detection

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline, turning-point

I am trying to seperate one data set into two splines and save the points in two different arrays.

[image: Data Set]

I need to do this to be able to interpolate between the points to get the spline and then in a final step to detect the turning points of each function. Background: All points represent nodes of a mesh of a part and I want to measure some distances which are at the turning points of the lower spline.

[image: Distances needed]

I tried this code to get the splines but it doesnt work because there are two  splines:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_coordinates = points_on_edges[:, 0]
z_coordinates = points_on_edges[:, 1]

interp_function = interp1d(y_coordinates, z_coordinates, kind='linear')

y_new = np.linspace(min(y_coordinates), max(y_coordinates), 500) 

z_new = interp_function(y_new)

plt.scatter(y_coordinates, z_coordinates, label='Datenpunkte', color='red')
plt.plot(y_new, z_new, label='Lineare Interpolation', color='blue')
plt.xlabel('y-Koordinate')
plt.ylabel('z-Koordinate')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Lineare Interpolation der Datenpunkte')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image: Result]

Trying to detect the turning points also didnt work, becuase of the two splines. Seperating them in the middle is also not an option, because the distance between the two splines varies.

[image: Alpha Shapes]

[image: Watershed relevant area]

Comment: your original image `kW4up.png` already contains more info then `jyLWf.png` and is almost the solution to the problem

Comment: one you clean the inner points, imagine setting a gaussian to each point the creates a "elevated terrain"  since points belonging to the same spline are close, they will form a mountain range. And between the two there will be a valley, separating both splines. you can run a watershed algorithm to separate both regions.

Comment: @rioV8 do you mean the picture I reuploaded as "Alpha Shapes"? Do you think I should use those edges to make the spline?

Comment: Thank you @SembeiNorimaki, I try to implement something like that

Comment: search the web for `convex hull`

Comment: @riov8 I already tried convex hull eralier. The result is worse than alpha edges

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I implemented a code using the watershed algorithm and added a picture at the end of the post. The separation is not ideal, but do you now a way how I can measure those distances shown in the picture?

Comment: once you know which points belong to the right curve, the most right point of the curve is the point with a maximum value of Y and Z<0. Similarly the most left point of the curve is the one with a lower y value and z between 0 and 1. the difference if that distance. For other distances you can apply a similar approach.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thank you! Do you know how I can separate the region I want to measure from the others? Using just the area its currently in is probably not enough, because this is just one result of an experiment and the curves vary (the genral shape remains the same)

Comment: Post your data?